# Limit of function tending to derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on $R$ such that
$$
 \lim_{x \to \infty} | f'(x) - f(x) | = 0.
$$
Can we say anything about $f$? For example, does there exist a constant $c \in R$ such that
$$
 \lim_{x \to \infty} | f(x) - c \cdot e^{x} | = 0?
$$

Comment: @David: And $f(x)=1/x$ satisfies Vincent's condition, with $c=0$.

Comment: @TonyK I missed that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the same approach as Gurvan, we have $g(x)=f'(x)-f(x)$ We know that $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to \infty$ and that $g$ is continuous everywhere. So  $\int_0^{\infty}g(t)e^{-t}dt=L$ exists.

Solving the differential equation, we have $f(x)=Ae^x+e^xL(x)$, where $L(x)=\int_0^{x}g(t)e^{-t}dt$.

Let $c= A+L$ Then $f(x)-ce^x=e^x(L-L(x))=e^x\int_x^{\infty}g(t)e^{-t}dt$.  As $g(x)\to 0$ , I can choose M such that, $g(x)<\epsilon$  For $ x>M$ Then $|e^x\int_x^{\infty}g(t)e^{-t}dt|<e^x\epsilon\int_x^{\infty}e^{-t}dt=\epsilon$ . So$ |f(x)-c e^x|<\epsilon$ for $x>M$ and $f(x)-ce^x\to 0 $, as $x\to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

You can define $g:x \mapsto f'(x)-f(x)$, knowing that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \to 0$.

Then solving the differential equation gives:
$$
 f(x) = c \cdot e^{x} + \int_0^x g(t)\cdot e^{x-t} \, dt
$$
But then I'm not sure you can conclude anything about $f$.

Comment: I don't see how you come from $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$ arrive at the differential equation... What you can say about finite $x$ is also weird, since there is nothing known of $f$ for finite $x$.